# Width transition - select the transition direct for increase and decrease width

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have a transition width rule on a `div` -

**CSS -**

```
div {
    height : 100px ; 
    width : 0px ; 
    transition-property: width;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
}

.show {
    width : 200px ;
}
```

**HTML -**

```
<div></div>
```

When I make toggle on the `show` class the transition occur by -

increase width -  from left to right  ,

decrease width -  from right to left  .

I want to make it such that  -

increase width -  from left to right ,

decrease width -  from **left to right**  .

How to achieve that ?

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("#btnShow").click(function () {
    $("div").addClass("show");
   });
   $("#btnHide").click(function () {
    $("div").removeClass("show");
   }); 
  });
```

```css
div {
  background-color: #b0c4de;
  height : 100px ; 
  width : 0px ; 
  transition-property: width;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
 }
 
 .show {
  width : 200px ;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
 <button type="button" id="btnShow">Show</button>
 <br>
 <button type="button" id="btnHide">Hide</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add another class `.hide`, give it a `width: 0` and `left: 200px`, which will move the box from left to right while the `width` is decreasing.

When the `.show` class is applied, only the `width` property is being animated, which will snap the `div` to its original position and when the `.hide` is being applied `width` and `left` are animated, which will animate `width` and `left` giving you exactly what you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnShow").click(function() {
    $("div").removeClass("hide").addClass("show");
  });
  $("#btnHide").click(function() {
    $("div").removeClass("show").addClass("hide");
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  background-color: #b0c4de;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
.show {
  transition-property: width;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
}
.hide {
  transition-property: width, left;
  width: 0;
  left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<button type="button" id="btnShow">Show</button>
<br />
<button type="button" id="btnHide">Hide</button>
```

Comment: Well, it works the first time you show and hide, but not after it.

Comment: It won't be hard I think. Maybe add `.show{left:0;width:200px;}` I think. Try it. Or you will have to add it on JQuery.

Comment: @azhpo - Well, the problem was it was transitioning all properties, I had to remove the transition for `left` property when the `.show` class is being applied. PROBELM SOLVED!!!

Answer (score 1):

1) Because the width of the div is 200px, we just initially place the div (when it is in it's hidden state) to the right....like this:

```
margin-left: 400px;
left: -200px
```

This ensures that the 'hide' transition goes the other way

2) Then for the 'show' state we remove the margin and left values so that the 'show' transition starts from the left.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/rw9xws6x/1/)**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnShow").click(function() {
    $("div").addClass("show");
  });
  $("#btnHide").click(function() {
    $("div").removeClass("show");
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  background-color: #b0c4de;
  height: 100px;
  width: 0px;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  position: relative;
  left: -200px;
  margin-left: 400px;
}
.show {
  width: 200px;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  transition-property: width;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<button type="button" id="btnShow">Show</button>
<br>
<button type="button" id="btnHide">Hide</button>
```